# R Summarize With DataTable

Tags: r, csv, data.table

```
data=data.frame("StudentID"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                "Class"=c(1,2,2,3,3),
                "Type"=c('A','A','B','B','B'))
```

Say you have data as shown above and you wish for summaries like this,
[image]

What is the effective solution to do this and output to a csv in organized way such as shown above?

---

Example data if there is weights involved and you wanted weighted counts and porporitons.portions.

```
data1=data.frame("StudentID"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                "Class"=c(1,2,2,3,3),
                "Type"=c('A','A','B','B','B'),
"Weighting"=c(10,6,13,12,2))
```

Comment: is it a single data.frame output for multiple

Comment: You'd have to output to two csvs because these are two different summaries.

Comment: @akrun yes one row is 'COUNT' and one is 'PROP' which is just the percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(names(data)[2:3], ~ 
    data %>% 
     select(.x) %>% 
     group_by_at(.x) %>% 
     summarise(COUNT = n()) %>% 
     mutate(PROP = COUNT/sum(COUNT)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  Class COUNT  PROP Type 
#* <dbl> <int> <dbl> <fct>
#1     1     1   0.2 <NA> 
#2     2     2   0.4 <NA> 
#3     3     2   0.4 <NA> 
#4    NA     2   0.4 A    
#5    NA     3   0.6 B
```

---

Or with `data.table` by `melt`ing into 'long' format

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(data), id.var = 'StudentID')[, .(COUNT = .N), 
  .(variable, value)][, PROP := COUNT/sum(COUNT),.(variable)][]
```

---

Or with `base R` using `table` and `prop.table`

```
 lapply(data[-1], function(x) {x1 <- table(x); x2 <- prop.table(x1); cbind(COUNT = x1, PROP = x2)})
```

Comment: I actually added a note to the question say for example if you wanted weighted counts (COUNT-W PROP-W) and unweighted to (COUNT PROP)

Comment: wondering if you have solution for using the weighted counts @akrun

Comment: @bvowe do you need `data1 %>% count(Type, wt = Weighting)`

Comment: i updated the question because that didn't seem to work. i am wondering about a data.table solution

Comment: @bvowe tryr `setDT(data1)[, sum(Weighting), Type]`

Comment: that is perfect but i am hoping for this for all variables. i tried setDT(data1)[, sum(Weighting),] but it did not work

Comment: @bvowe can you be more specific, i ddidn't get you.  Do you need it orr `StudentID`

Comment: thank you i apologize. I am hoping for the same output shown in the question but have them weighted. So it is the same exact format with counts and proportions for all variables but they are weighted counts and proportions. @akrun

Comment: @bvowe. which format you need.  is it the second one with `data.table` `melt`

Comment: thank you it works perfect for 'Type' but i need for all variables in my data table

Comment: @bvowe do you need  `melt(setDT(data1), id.var = c('StudentID',  'Weighting'))[, sum(Weighting), .(variable, value)]`

Comment: perfect! thank you again for taking the time to explain this to me

Answer (score 1):

Both summaries are simple, here I use `dplyr`. To combine them in the way you want, it's going to need to be slapped together in a somewhat inelegant way. You can remove the name `col1` if you want

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data %>% group_by(Class) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n(), Prop = n() / nrow(data))


df2 <- data %>% group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(Count = n(), Prop = n() / nrow(data))

names(df1)[1] <- 'col1'
names(df2)[1] <- 'col1'

rbind(
  c('Class', '', ''),
  df1,
  c('Type', '', ''),
  df2
)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  col1  Count Prop 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Class ""    ""   
2 1     1     0.2  
3 2     2     0.4  
4 3     2     0.4  
5 Type  ""    ""   
6 A     2     0.4  
7 B     3     0.6
```